# Echo $row database value inside a javascript

Tags: javascript, php

How can i display database value $row in javascript?

At line 3 `const source = 'https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8';` I want the link/url get from database. base on url id domain.com/video.php?id=12

I already try like this but doesn't work `const source = '<?php echo $row["video_url"]; ?>'`

Here is the code

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const source = 'https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8';
    const video = document.querySelector('video');
    
    // For more options see: https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/#options
    // captions.update is required for captions to work with hls.js
    const player = new Plyr(video, {captions: {active: true, update: true, language: 'en'}});
    
    if (!Hls.isSupported()) {
        video.src = source;
    } else {
        // For more Hls.js options, see https://github.com/dailymotion/hls.js
        const hls = new Hls();
        hls.loadSource(source);
        hls.attachMedia(video);
        window.hls = hls;
        
        // Handle changing captions
        player.on('languagechange', () => {
            // Caption support is still flaky. See: https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/issues/994
            setTimeout(() => hls.subtitleTrack = player.currentTrack, 50);
        });
    }
    
    // Expose player so it can be used from the console
    window.player = player;
});
</script>
```

EDITED: The output for this script is empty `const source = ''`

Comment: What's the output when you try `const source = '<?php echo $row["video_url"]; ?>'`?

Comment: before the script tag put this: `<?php echo '<pre>'.print_r($row,1).'</pre>';?>` and show in your question what the output is

Comment: @Cully nothing, just empty.

Comment: @Haqem Then your `$row` variable is not being populated. Please show us the code that populates that variable.